# Rails 5 crash in .erb file but only when running on server

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, erb

so i have this code in my erb file:

```
<% a = ["Apple","Orange","Banana","Carrot","Turnip","Rabbit","Lion"] %>
<% arr = @things.where(:active => 1).sort_by{|el| a.index(el[:name])}%>
<% for product in arr %>
```

and its crashing on line 2 with this error:

```
comparison of Fixnum with nil failed
```

I replaced it with this:

```
<% arr = @things.sort_by{|el| a.index(el[:name])}%>
```

and its still crashing... when i change the entire code block with this:

```
<% for thing in @things %>
```

the crash goes away.
its odd because it runs fine locally.

Comment: It is because some value is `nil`

Comment: `a.index(el[:name]` is returning `nil` for some value there is one value in `@things` which is not in `a`

Comment: Can you describe what the table looks like and what the desired result is? This is the most godawful code I have seen all day.

Comment: @max explaining why it's not great code would be a lot more useful to the OP than just saying it's "godawful", which doesn't add any value to the topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It cannot find in array `a` element with `el[:name]` so it returns `nil` and cannot sort.

Put ternary operator and return `-1` if not found:

```
<% a = ["Apple","Orange","Banana","Carrot","Turnip","Rabbit","Lion"] %>
<% arr = @things.where(:active => 1).select{|el| !a.index(el[:name]).nil?} %>
<% arr = arr.sort_by{|el| a.index(el[:name])} %>
```

or better filter it and then sort it:

```
<% a = ["Apple","Orange","Banana","Carrot","Turnip","Rabbit","Lion"] %>
<% arr = @things.where(:active => 1).select{|el| !a.index(el[:name]).nil?}.sort_by{|el| a.index(el[:name])} %>
```

Comment: works great! thanks. i can accept your answer in a couple of mins. :)